# German working visa - criminal record

Tags: visas, germany

I'm a New Zealander looking to obtain a job seeker and then working visa in Germany. I understand I can apply for the jobseeker visa after I arrive in Berlin on a tourist visa.

My issue is that I was recently given a police caution from UK police for having a tiny amount of weed on me in Belfast. Even though its not a conviction, I understand it will show up on a police record check and DBS. I have had no prior cautions or checks. T

Does anyone know if I should have any issues obtaining a German working visa? Hopefully they are only concerned with convictions, and if I do disclose it it shouldn't prevent me from getting a visa? (I know Berlin is liberal with personal possession of weed).

Comment: No conviction, mean never happened (nearly). and it should not be on record. For **crime** you need to go to a judge, and judge should sentence you as culpable. Crimes are very bad act against society (so you may deserve losing some freedoms). Most of unlawful acts are not crimes, and so police/authorities could make you to pay something (or other remedies). But policier are not judicial authorities, so they cannot record crimes. You must check with UK authorities if you committed a crime, and if it is recorded.